# Mac: AVD wont launch

Tags: android, macos, android-virtual-device

I am trying to use AVD on MAc. It was working fine before but now for an unknown reason it wont launched. If I try to launch the virtual device from AVD manager, I get the window saying "Starting Android Emulator" but the emulator dosent start and the window disappears after progress bar reaches the end. If I try to delete the device form the AVD a message pops up saying Android Virtual Device is currently running in the emulator and cannot be deleted.

Comment: Are you using one or two monitors? Can you create a new AVD that works and its the old AVD that is broken.

Comment: I am extending to an external monitor. Yes, I can create a new AVD and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33462

I've also encountered problems with closing the emulator on the second monitor on a Mac. Either don't close the emulator on the second monitor or use the workaround in the ticket and modify the emulator-user.ini file for the window.x and window.y values when you do.