# Error on launching AVD in Android Studio, ERROR says eglMakeCurrent failed

Tags: android, android-studio

```
emulator: device fd:668
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 0 0 240 400
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
eglMakeCurrent failed
```

What is "eglMakeCurrent failed"?

**TRIED**
to set the window.x = 0 window.y = 0 ... 
but window.x=322 keeps coming back... I tried changing the resolution....plus 
can't even move the emulator..tried ALT+SPACE and 'move'...but can't move 
it.. Although the emulator can be started –

Comment: Even though I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652311/emulator-emulator-window-was-out-of-view-and-was-recentered , if you use two monitors - it could be - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204301/mac-avd-wont-launch/14204530#14204530

Comment: I am having the same exact issue. Sometimes it starts it works fine for a bit and then suddenly it just outputs eglMakeCurrent and the emulator screen goes black. I am on Linux with KVM enabled. AMD processor so no HAXM.

Answer (score 4):

In **AVD Manager**, change **Boot option** to **Cold Boot**. Then boot up the virtual device. After that you can change it back to **Quick Boot**. This usually happens if you modify something and the changes don't apply correctly.

[Explicative Image(I hope)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFb4r.png)

Comment: You can also use the down arrow in Action section and `Cold Boot Now`. It solved my problem.

Comment: if you are not using UI the command is 
    emulator -avd MyEmulatorAPI22 -no-snapshot-load

Answer (score 2):

In **AVD Manager**, change **Emulated Performance - Graphics** to **Software - GLES 2.0**

I ran into this after setting up multiple monitors using different graphics cards.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server

emulator -avd <avd_name> -no-snapshot-load
```

It works 100% if you have setup environment variable and PATH correctly.